# Measuring wifi file-transfer speed in python

Tags: python, performance, sockets, file-transfer

I am trying to measure the speed of file transfer through sockets in python. I set up measurements on both ends (sending and receiving side) and get somewhat different results (i.e. 16 vs 17 Mbps for a 1MB file transferred via ad-hoc wifi). My question is whether this kind of difference is something I should expect, given the measurement setup following. This is all running on two Raspberry Pi models 2 B.

sender:

```
import socket as s
sock = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((addr,5000))
start = t.time()
sock.sendall(data)
finish = t.time()
```

receiver:

```
import socket as s
sock = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(s.SOL_SOCKET, s.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(("", 5000))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()
pack = []
start = t.time()
while True:
    piece = conn.recv(8192)
    if not piece:
        finish = t.time()
        break
    pack.append(piece.decode())
```

Also very welcome, any other transfer speed measurements advices, if there is any way to do this better.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [speedtest-cli](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli) what are you locking for. Also, there is a good [article](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/03/measuring-internet-speed-in-python-using-speedtest-cli/) about it. It seems that Raspberry Pi supported.

> Matt Martz has created a Python project called speedtest-cli which allows you to do a basic upload/download measurement using SpeedNet’s infrastructure. It works fine on the Pi and is really easy to try out on the command line.

If you want make your own script, anyway `speedtest_cli.py` good place to start.